# Travelling with sealed processor

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, dubai, philippines

I'm going back home (The Philippines) next week from Italy, travelling with Emirates.

Where can I put my sealed processor ([Pentium G4560](https://www.amazon.it/Intel-Pentium-G4560-3-5GHz-Kaby-Lake/dp/B01NBSOQ6J)) that I bought from amazon.it (€65), checked luggage or hand carry?

Do they have to tax me if they see my new processor?

Comment: What do you mean by a "sealed processor"? Food processor? Computer processor in original packaging?

Comment: Its the new pentium g4560. Sealed proccesor means new cause in my country is always late. So where do i put it in my luggage or carry do they have to check it then put a tax on it? its only 65 euro.

Answer (score 1):

Even if your question is unclear, the answer will likely not depend on which exact item you are bringing.

Airport security may require that you break any seals if they for some reason want to inspect the item in greater detail. It does not matter if it is in your hand luggage or checked luggage. If you refuse to break the seal, they may not allow you to bring the item, but have you dispose of it.

Going through customs when entering the Phillipines, customs officers will also be entitled to break the seal if a more thorough inspection is required. Here, you can not expect to have the option to dispose of the item, since the customs officers will be interested in uncovering even the attempt to import illegal products, substances, whatever.

If you have to pay any duty when importing the item depends on the value of the product. If the [IATA page on Phillipine customs regulations](http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/PH-Philippines-customs-currency-airport-tax-regulations-details.htm) is up to date, you are allowed to freely bring 'one non-consumable item with a value of max. USD 200'.